# jQuery $(document).ready() issue - jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a page on which I am loading a select tag with options that I am getting from an ajax call to a service. It is working just fine and loading the select tag correctly. I only want this loading to happen once when the user first arrives at the page so I put the call to the function that does this inside the $(document).ready(function call. The problem that I am seeing is that when the user selects one of the options and then clicks a button under certain circumstances I pop a dialog (jQuery UI) telling them they need to take a certain action. The first time this happen and only the first time the selected option is getting reset somehow to the first option in the list. I ran in debug many times and discovered that if this is the first time on the page the selector is loaded on arrival at the page as is expected but if the dialog gets popped it is loaded again - only the first time - after that if the dialog gets popped the reload does not occur and all is well. The abbreviated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.LoadStuff();
});

jQuery.fn.LoadStuff = function () {
    //load up the select tag with options
};
```

`LoadStuff` does not get called anywhere else. selOffers is the select tag and dvConflict is the dialog. They are not sharing a common parent div.

```
<select id="selOffers"></select> 

<div id="dvConflict"><div id="dvConflictMsg" /></div>
```

jQuery for the dialog:

```
var optSave = {
width: 400,
modal: true,
resizable: false,
draggable: false,
closeOnEscape: true,
zIndex: 1320,
buttons: [
    {
        text: 'Ok',
        click: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
]
```

}

```
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide(); //Hides the title
```

$('#dvConflict').css('background', 'none'); //Takes out our custom background
$('#dvConflict').dialog(optSave);

Comment: i think you should call it as  $.LoadStuff(); not  $.fn.LoadStuff();

Comment: my gut is telling me you have a race condition somewhere... are you able to post more specific code?

Comment: i think just call it as LoadStuff();

Comment: It works just fine for me that way... maybe there is something wrong somewhere else. What version jQuery are you using?

Comment: I updated the title to reflect the version

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Two things

1. Use `$.LoadStuff = function () { }` instead of `$.fn.LoadStuff = function () {...}`. The first is to be called at any context via `$.LoadStuff();`. The latter is to be used on an element-selection, like `$("div.to-load").LoadStuff();`.
2. `$(document).ready` is fired every time the DOM finishes loading. In some AJAX calls, you could be reloading parts of your DOM, or an internal frame (I don't know, though I don't have your code).

   The following code sample will help you bypass the problem:

   ```
   var first = true;  
   $(document).ready(function () {  
       if (first) $.LoadStufF();  
       ...    
       first = false;  
   }
   ```
3. When opening a dialog, make sure there are no `<script>` tags inside the dialog-wrapped element. Say you have the code line:

   ```
   $('#dialoged').dialog({ ... });
   ```

   So a bad practice is to have:

   ```
   <div id="dialoged">
       <script>
            var first = true;  
            $(document).ready(function () {  
                if (first) $.LoadStufF();  
                    ...    
                first = false;  
            }
        </script>
   </div>
   ```

Comment: This does not break the code but has the same result. In debug the function still gets executed twice the first time you got to the page and then cause the dialog to pop.

Comment: This still has the issue - the offending line of code that causes the issue is $('#dvMyPop').dialog(optSave); - this dialog and div have nothing to do with the select tag but somehow it causes $.LoadStuff() to fire.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `<script>` tag inside `#dvMyPop`?

Comment: No - but I did do one further test and proved without a doubt that it is the single line calling the dialog that is the problem. I commented that line out and popped an alert instead and all was well - changed it back to popping the dialog and the select gets incorrectly reloaded again. I will edit my original question and add the HTML for you to see.

Comment: Again - there is no script code inside the div tag. The options for the dialog only contain the code for the 'OK' button which closes the dialog but I added the jQuery that pops the dialog up at the top with the rest of the code